# NPX create-react-app aborting installation after vulnerabilities found

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to start learning React and JSX but I have been running into problems with using create-react-app. Every time I have used it eventually states that it is aborting installation and that `npm install --save save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts` has failed. It also state before the installation aborts that there were a number of packages added and a certain number of vulnerabilities found. I have tried searching for other ways to create a React app from scratch and have followed these tutorials to only run into problems and have these fail as well.

Node Version 10.15.2 --  Same error occurred. 
Reverted to Node Version 8.15.1  -- Same error still occurs.

NPM version 5.8.0 has not been changed.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Has not changed receiving the error.

If someone could shed some light on what I might try next or what additional information might be helpful I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you. Here is what my screen looks like after trying `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming Courses\YouTube Tutorials\Learn React.js>npx c
reate-react-app my
'0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming Courses\YouTube Tu
torials\Learn React.js\my.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

'0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
+ react-dom@16.8.3
+ react@16.8.3
+ react-scripts@2.1.5
added 1813 packages from 716 contributors and audited 36230 packages in 77.867s
found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts
 has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Programming Courses\YouTube Tutorials\Learn React.js>
```