# create-react-app command aborting installation Why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

windows 10 
node v10.15.1
npm v6.8.0;

```
I:\>npx create-react-app newpomodoro
```

Creating a new React app in I:\newpomodoro.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^2.2.x","topo":"1.x'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-03T17_21_57_703Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting newpomodoro/ from I:\
Done.

I installed react globaly and loacaly as well but still it was giving me same error.
Can anyBody tell me whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same problem with `npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts` has failed. Mine then deletes node_modules and package.json. I have asked about this here: [NPX create-react-app aborting installation after vulnerabilities found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951718/npx-create-react-app-aborting-installation-after-vulnerabilities-found)

I have already tried to use `npm cache clean --force` but this has not solved the problem. I have also tried installing different versions of node.js to no avail.

Comment: Did you find any solution.

Comment: I have not found a working solution yet. Still working on it. I am new to programming, though, so I was hoping someone on here would have some input into possible steps to take.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. I don't know if you might have been in the same boat, but the cause was a space in my path name. I often save my projects on google file stream which has a space in the name ("G:/My Drive/..."). I tried creating the app in another directory and moving the folder which ended up working out.

Answer (score 0):

The command `npm clean --cache` won't help.

If you are facing an abort installation error in react.

The abort installation error generated because of the older node version.
you should update your node package version.

To solve, run the following command and it will solve the abort installation error.

```
nvm install node 12.18.0
```

So, update your node package to the latest one. Once you've updated your node package then create your react app as follows:

```
npx create-react-app <your-app-name>
```

The abort installation error occurred because the outdated version of your node was not supporting the `create-react-app` command and deleted the `node_modules` and `package.json` file

Try this, please. It solved my error and hopefully, it'll solve your error too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in node version just update it to latest version and it work's for me!

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

here is the solution which works for me, first of all, you should update all of your dependencies
then ran the command

```
npm cache clean --force
```

after that you can use

```
npx create-react-app
```